# Hide and show button for frames in framesets

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm making a project with two frames in framesets on each side of the page.
The frame on the left is called "left" and the one on the right is called "right".
I'm trying to assign a "Hide/Show" button for the left frame; that button will be assigned on the left frame and it will hide the left frame, thus making the right frame wider.
I tried searching but i got no solution.

I'm new to this web designing thing, so, it would be an honor if someone lends me a helping hand.I hope i didn't make things too complicated.

Thank you,
Looking forward to your kind replies.........

Comment: Please show us your existing code - [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I *strongly* advise: DO NOT USE FRAMESETS.

Comment: I agree with the 2 comments above 100%

Comment: is there any other way to achieve the same facilities which i get from framesets through any other elements???

Comment: Im looking for the following things in my element:
1)little coding
2)resizable with browser window.
3)and also a splitter which seperates the two halves (they should be resizable by the client)

Comment: Can you help me sir???
:(

Comment: OOH BTW..MY CURRENT CODING:
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<frameset cols="20%,80%" border="1" bordercolor="#fff" id="frameset">
  <frame src="left.aspx" name="left" id="left">
  <frame src="right.aspx" name="right" id="right">
</frameset> 
</html>

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned frames will probably get you into trouble.  The easiest route is probably to just wrap your two columns in divs.  A class on the `<body>` tag dictates the width and visibility of both.  The process of "hiding" and "showing" the left-most column is just a matter of toggling which class is on the body tag using javascript.

Here's a quick example.

```
<body class="two-col">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a id="hide-sidebar">Hide</a>
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Right
  </div>
</body>

body.two-col .sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

body.two-col .main {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

body.one-col .sidebar {
  display: none;
}

$('#hide-sidebar').click(function() {
  body = $('body');
  if (body.hasClass('one-col')) {
    body.addClass('two-col').removeClass('one-col');
  } else {
    body.addClass('one-col').removeClass('two-col');
  }
});
```

Comment: i know that's a solution to the hide and show..
but actually i need the two divisions to be resizable just like the frames in framesets..........
can you help?

Comment: u know...something like jsfiddle but with a collapsible button